# XPath results seems to secretly have more data

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm parsing an XML document with Nokogiri and searching for a specific section and assigning it to a variable. Then, I search that node and the results seem to be from the entire document as opposed to that small section.

Example:

```
data = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("something.xml"))
section = data.xpath("//w:tr[.//w:t[contains(., '#something#')]]").
section.xpath("//wp:docPr")
```

However, the XPath on section returns results that aren't even in the output of `puts section`.

```
<w:tr w:rsidR="00B76A6E">
        <w:tc>
          <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="9035" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:tcBorders>
              <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="0A57A4"/>
            </w:tcBorders>
            <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
          </w:tcPr>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00B76A6E" w:rsidRDefault="00D85F67">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:jc w:val="left"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>#something#</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
          <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="1705" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:tcBorders>
              <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="0A57A4"/>
            </w:tcBorders>
            <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
          </w:tcPr>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00B76A6E" w:rsidRDefault="00D85F67">
            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
              </w:rPr>
              <w:drawing>
                <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="79A6C53C" wp14:editId="0DE97A9F">
                  <wp:extent cx="292608" cy="292608"/>
                  <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
                  <wp:docPr id="924" name="Picture 924"/>
                  <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
                  </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                  <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                      <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                        <pic:nvPicPr>
                          <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="S-sm.png"/>
                          <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                        </pic:nvPicPr>
                        <pic:blipFill>
                          <a:blip r:embed="rId20" cstate="print">
                            <a:extLst>
                              <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                              </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                          </a:blip>
                          <a:stretch>
                            <a:fillRect/>
                          </a:stretch>
                        </pic:blipFill>
                        <pic:spPr>
                          <a:xfrm>
                            <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                            <a:ext cx="292608" cy="292608"/>
                          </a:xfrm>
                          <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                            <a:avLst/>
                          </a:prstGeom>
                        </pic:spPr>
                      </pic:pic>
                    </a:graphicData>
                  </a:graphic>
                </wp:inline>
              </w:drawing>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
```

This is very confusing. I'm trying get the value of `id` in the `<wp:DocPr>` tag but it returns a lot of them like this:

```
section.xpath("//wp:docPro")
<wp:docPr id="225" name="Picture 225"/>
<wp:docPr id="226" name="Picture 226"/>
<wp:docPr id="227" name="Picture 227"/>
<wp:docPr id="228" name="Picture 228"/>
<wp:docPr id="924" name="Picture 924"/>
<wp:docPr id="926" name="Picture 926"/>
<wp:docPr id="925" name="Picture 925"/>
<wp:docPr id="927" name="Picture 927"/>
<wp:docPr id="229" name="Picture 229"/>
<wp:docPr id="230" name="Picture 230"/>
<wp:docPr id="346" name="Picture 6"/>
<wp:docPr id="17" name="Picture 6"/>
<wp:docPr id="3" name="Picture 6"/>
<wp:docPr id="7" name="Picture 6"/>
<wp:docPr id="255" name="Picture 6"/>
<wp:docPr id="304" name="Picture 6"/>
<wp:docPr id="313" name="Picture 6"/>
```

Comment: Please provide a MINIMAL example of the XML. That means the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that wastes our time when trying to help you. Also, your XML is invalid. Please make sure it's correct as that can cause problems when parsing and trying to answer.

Comment: There can be no "secret data" in XML - it's wide open and viewable, which immediately should tell you there's a problem in the XPath itself.

Comment: Any additional data relation to an xpath or node could also be due to some additional jquery in there

Comment: My apologies for the extra few lines of code... However, I've gotten this straightened out already... Thanks. Also, I didn't really mean secret... I just used the term to get my point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a dot `.` at the beginning of your XPath to make it relative to current context element :

```
section.xpath(".//wp:docPr")
```

you already use the same concept for expression inside the predicate of the first XPath (this one to be clear: `.//w:t[contains(., '#something#')]`), but forgot it in the second XPath.